# Edit link in theme_table drupal

Tags: drupal

I have created a table in drupal to display the records. How can i add the edit link to each record so that it goes to an input form corresponding to the id for that record

```
    function display($nid){
$query = db_query("select * from {contactus}");
$data = array();
$i = 0;
while($row = db_fetch_array($query)){
    $data[$i] = $row;

    $i++;
}
$output = theme_table(array('id','email','comment'),$data);
return $output;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You must implement the full CRUD-range, Create Read Update Delete. Right now you only have an index. For Drupal7 there is a good example in [dbtng](http://drupalcode.org/viewvc/drupal/contributions/modules/examples/dbtng_example/dbtng_example.module?view=markup) (from the [examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples))

For Drupal 6 I am not aware of such an example.

Basically the pattern is:

1. make hook_menu-items with callbacks, one for the index, Read, Update, Delete, Create.
2. The Read item simply shows the item (item/%id)
3. The Update shows a form to update the item (item/%id/edit). Form is pre-filled. See FormApi in Drupal for more information on forms.
4. The Delete shows a `confirm_form()` with a callback to delete the entry from the database.
5. The Create shows a form to create a new item. Form is empty.

But to answer your exact quesion, in Drupal you create a link with [l()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/l/6). `l('foo', 'item/bar')` Will create a `<a href="/item/bar">foo</a>`.